# Refine jQuery selector to target correct input element

Tags: jquery, closest

I have a function that writes a value from a select to an input. I am using a live("change", function to trigger this.

```
if ($(this).val( ) == 'MyValue') {$(".my_input").val(VarValue);}
```

This works fine but I need to target the closest input so it only writes to that one input and not all of them. What I have tried below does not work. Please help if you can, thanks.

```
if ($(this).val( ) == 'MyValue') {$(this).closest(".my_input").val(VarValue);}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is a link to the Jsfiddle, please note, the functionality is not working here, but you can see my html. http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/9x6kv/

Comment: `closest()` means *first ancestor element that matches*.

Comment: What does "closest" mean? Please show us your HTML.

Comment: Please include html markup in your answer

Comment: Folks cannot advise on the proper jQuery for targeting a specific element without seeing the relevant HTML.  It's a waste of everyone's time to guess what your markup looks like.

Comment: I have added a link to a fiddle, the functions are not working here, I am still working on that but you can see the html. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle, but it works :[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/qkKZ4/1/)

You had an issue with your js - Change:

```
$(".clone_dept").live("change", function() { //<-- not really sure why live isn't working
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #1') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_1);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #2') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_1);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #3') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_1);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #4') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_1);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #5') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_1);}
    }).change(); // trigger once if needed
}); // <-- This shouldnt be here
```

to:

```
$(".clone_dept").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #1') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_1);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #2') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_2);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #3') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_3);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #4') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_4);}
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #5') {$(".clone_attendees").val(dept_5);}
}).change(); // trigger once if needed
```

Although this doesn't really address how to select the closest input. In the case of your fiddle, it's the only element that's using that class. If this row structure is going to be copied and reused, use this to select the right input.

```
if($(this).val() == 'Dept #1') {$(this).parent().next("td").children(".clone_attendees").val(dept_1);}
```

Edit:
Better yet, use an array to assign the right value rather than having 5 lines of if statments.

```
var dept = ["Person #1, Person #2, Person #3, Person #4, Person #5","Person #6, Person #7, Person #8, Person #9, Person #10","Finance Persons","IT Persons","Marketing Persons"];
```

add values to the option tags

```
<option value=0>Dept #1</option>
```

and then

```
$(".clone_dept").change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == 'Dept #1') {
        $(this).parent()
        .next("td")
        .children(".clone_attendees")
        .val(dept[$(this).val()])
    }
}).change(); // trigger once if needed
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Final Code (if someone needs)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $theme = $("#clonned").clone();
// The Function in Question
var dept_1 = "Person #1, Person #2, Person #3, Person #4, Person #5";
var dept_2 = "Person #6, Person #7, Person #8, Person #9, Person #10";
var dept_3 = "Finance Persons";
var dept_4 = "IT Persons";
var dept_5 = "Marketing Persons";

$(".clone_dept").live("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #1') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1) .clone_attendees").val(dept_1);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #2') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1) .clone_attendees").val(dept_2);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #3') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1) .clone_attendees").val(dept_3);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #4') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1) .clone_attendees").val(dept_4);
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'Dept #5') {
        $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1) .clone_attendees").val(dept_5);
    }
}).change(); // trigger once if needed
// Clone Function
$(".tr_clone_add").live('click', function() {
    var $newone = $theme.clone();
    $newone.attr("id", "clonned"+Math.floor(Math.random()*11));
    $newone.appendTo('.table_clone');
});
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I am unfortunately using tables so the input is in the next td so next() didnt work. Cheers

Comment: Hi, thanks Alper, but that option does not work when using tables :(
See here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/gStHG/3/

Comment: Thanks Alper but on that fiddle, I can't get the clone() function to work. The Add button clones the tr. When this happens there is a problem with the select populating all of the inputs not just the one on that row. Cheers

Comment: what would be your final result? i mean, when you cick add button then you want to clone current (with values) and put new (empty) one above?

Comment: Thanks for all your help and effort, this answer looks good but someone else got there sooner, sorry

Comment: no problem but i strongly advice that use a theme system to cloning so you don't need change the values for different elements, see http://jsfiddle.net/9x6kv/15/

Answer (score 0):

if you're sure there is at least one, you can try

```
if ($(this).val( ) == 'MyValue') {$(".my_input").eq(0).val(VarValue);}
```

that gets the first from the set, but it doesn't have any idea of 'closest'

first sibling? try

```
if ($(this).val( ) == 'MyValue') {$(this).siblings(".my_input").eq(0).val(VarValue);}
```

but that will get any that appear BEFORE yours anyway. totally depends what 'closest' means

Comment: Thanks Luke I tried these but they didnt work, I have added a link to a fiddle, the functions are not working but you can see the html. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is next in the DOM, this should work:

```
if ($(this).val( ) == 'MyValue') {$(this).next().val(VarValue);}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I am unfortunately using tables so the input is in the next td so next() didnt work. I have added a fiddle in the question. Cheers